# iText 7 Get all text chunks and their location

Tags: itext, itext7

I'm trying to get all the individual text chucks and their location using iText7.  I need to parse the chucks and let a user select specific texted to be parsed from future identical PDFs.  I need to have the user select the employee name, ID, and other text.  I will then store the location of that data to use in processing future PDFS. The selection/mapping is a one time setup. Here is an example of the data I have returning in iText 5:

| X | Y | chunk Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.763889 | 282.9278 | 11225 North Sourth St, Bedrock, ND, 99780, Ph: 999 321-6543 |
| 15.166975 | 277.17752 | Employee ID |
| 67.3675 | 277.17752 | Employee Name |
| 18.458744 | 272.22098 | 001159 |
| 68.33058 | 272.22098 | Fred Flintstone |

The below code works in iText 5 and I'm trying got migrate it to iText 7 for a project.  Some of the objects are no longer exposed in iText 7.

```
void Main()
{
    string filename = @"C:\Employee Info.pdf";
    
    using (var reader = new PdfReader(filename))
    {

        var parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);

        var strategy = parser.ProcessContent(1, new LocationTextExtractionStrategyWithPosition());

        // work with the locatins on the chucks to provide list to user.

        reader.Close();
    }
}


public class LocationTextExtractionStrategyWithPosition : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
{
    public readonly List<TextChunk> locationalResult = new List<TextChunk>();

    private readonly ITextChunkLocationStrategy tclStrat;

    public LocationTextExtractionStrategyWithPosition() : this(new TextChunkLocationStrategyDefaultImp())
    {
    }

    public LocationTextExtractionStrategyWithPosition(ITextChunkLocationStrategy strat)
    {
        tclStrat = strat;
    }

    public override void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        LineSegment segment = renderInfo.GetBaseline();
        if (renderInfo.GetRise() != 0)
        { // remove the rise from the baseline - we do this because the text from a super/subscript render operations should probably be considered as part of the baseline of the text the super/sub is relative to 
            Matrix riseOffsetTransform = new Matrix(0, -renderInfo.GetRise());
            segment = segment.TransformBy(riseOffsetTransform);
        }
        TextChunk tc = new TextChunk(renderInfo.GetText(), tclStrat.CreateLocation(renderInfo, segment));
        //tc.Dump();
        locationalResult.Add(tc);
    }
}

public class TextLocation
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [iText pdf2Data](https://pdf2data.online/)? It serves the exact purpose you describe

Comment: I had not looked at pdf2Data.  I have done some looking since your suggestion.  One question I have is how well does pdf2data handle variable-length forms?  If a form could be one page or multiple pages, will pdf2data look for sentenial values and skip pages to find the start of the next form?

Comment: pdf2Data is capable of skipping some repeated page headers/footers